# Deferred binding failed error

Tags: gwt

I am unable to solve this exception. I am trying to implement the cell table in gwt which is in GWT showcase. Below is my exception.

```
16:22:23.853 [ERROR] [celltablepagination] Unable to load module entry point class com.igs.celltablepagination.client.CellTablePagination (see associated exception for details)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.igs.celltablepagination.client.ContactDatabase$DatabaseConstants' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:57)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:85)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.ContactDatabase.&lt;init&gt;(ContactDatabase.java:321)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.ContactDatabase.get(ContactDatabase.java:304)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.ContactInfoForm.&lt;init&gt;(ContactInfoForm.java:52)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.CellTablePagination.onModuleLoad(CellTablePagination.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:605)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:57)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:85)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.ContactDatabase.&lt;init&gt;(ContactDatabase.java:321)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.ContactDatabase.get(ContactDatabase.java:304)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.ContactInfoForm.&lt;init&gt;(ContactInfoForm.java:52)
    at com.igs.celltablepagination.client.CellTablePagination.onModuleLoad(CellTablePagination.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I am getting here in the below part..

```
   interface DatabaseConstants extends Constants {
        String[] contactDatabaseCategories();
    }
    DatabaseConstants constants = GWT.create(DatabaseConstants.class);
```

Comment: Is there really no other log? (particularly **before** that `[ERROR]` message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a few things first check you have a `DatabaseConstants.properties` file to store the values, next ensure that the key `contactDatabaseCategories` exists and has a comma separated list of values. Also might have to create the constants as a stand alone class

**UPDATE**

Move the interface to it's own .java file
Create a text file called `DatabaseConstants.properties` at the same level as the .java file
within that you can put

```
contactDatabaseCategories=Category1,Category2
```

That should stop that error and provide you a value for more information take a look at [constants](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Constants.html)

Comment: I tried to implement the example from GWT schowcase  http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable.. I copied all the code from there.. there is no implementation for DatabaseConstants.. Please suggest how to proceed??