# Use Constants interface in GWT Project

Tags: java, gwt, interface, constants, uibinder

I have not yet used `Constants` interface in `GWT` and I am having problem to run the example [CellTable](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?locale=en#!CwCellTable). The deferred binding fails and the central error message is: "**No resource found for contactDataBaseCategories**". `contactDataBaseCategories` is a method defined in the interface `DataBaseConstants` and returns an array of Strings. I suspect I must create a properties (txt?) file and to define the categories, but I am not sure, since I come across this case for the first time. How can I do it properly to make the example of the `CellTable` run?

**Update:** I have created the ContactDatabase.DatabaseConstants.properties file in the same package in which the interface is declared, I have added the line in the file:

contactDataBaseCategories = friends, coWorkers, other

but it still does not work. The error is again : "No resource found for contactDataBaseCategories" and then

"Deferred Binding failed for com.al.celltablöeexample.ContactDatabase.DatabaseConstants".

What going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is how i do it

**Constant** interface

```
public interface DataBaseConstants extends Constants
{
    @Key("contact-database-categories")
    String contactDataBaseCategories();
}
```

property file. DataBaseConstants.properties

```
contact-database-categories = "Your String"
```

You can use it

```
public DataBaseConstants dbConstant= GWT.create( DataBaseConstants .class );

dbConstant.contactDataBaseCategories();
```

**Edited**
If you want to pass string array then you can do it like this

```
@DefaultStringArrayValue({"cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5"})
  String[] contactDataBaseCategories();
```

[More](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Constants.html) about Constants

Comment: Yes, but the method in the interface returns String[], and I still cannot perceive what value should I pass to String "contact-database-categories" and how it influences the application. Should I moreover do the same for the interface "CwConstants", which contains several methods?

Comment: i have edited the answer accordingly. Also if you need more details please visit the link i have provided. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed it. The problem was that it could not find the resource/file: `ContactDatabase.DatabaseConstants.properties`. I have changed it to `DatabaseConstants.properties` and I removed the inner interface to its own file. The same I did in the class `CwCellTable` on the interface `CwConstants`. In the [example page](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?locale=en#!CwCellTable) moreover, the instantiation of the `CwConstants` interface is missed, and one must do also this (in the constructor), like in the `ContactDatabase` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Dilantha's answer you can then set

```
contact-database-categories = Family, Friends, Coworkers, Businesses, Contacts
```

in order to comply with the example.

Tip : In order to make the example work create a costructor in CwCellList and add the following :

```
initWidget(onInitialize());
```

Comment: similar question for reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056765/deferred-binding-failed-error